# Flex Viewstack's children, if you can't see them, do they exist?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, adobe, viewstack

I seem to be running into an issue (Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference) binding events in actionscript to a viewstack layer not currently showing. Are those objects not created until that layer is visible for the first time? I remember something about a creation policy, if this is the case, can I force it to create those children before that layer is viewed?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, that's right -- ViewStack children are created only when needed by default ("deferred instantiation" is a phrase you'll hear thrown around in this context).  If instead you want to instruct Flex to create all of the ViewStack container's children up front, consider using the **creationPolicy** property common to all `mx.core.Containers`:

> A creationPolicy of
>   ContainerCreationPolicy.ALL means that
>   the navigator containers immediately
>   create deeper descendants for each
>   child, rather than waiting until that
>   child is selected.

```
<mx:ViewStack id="myStack" creationPolicy="all" />
```

It's a bit slower on startup, because you're creating a bunch of child components you might not need yet, but as long as you keep that tradeoff in mind, it may come in handy sometime.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, I had this same problem myself while working on an application with a PureMVC structure. I was unable to create mediators for the subcomponents of a ViewStack because they were constructed lazily by the Flex framework.

Here's where I eventually found my solution:

http://forums.puremvc.org/index.php?topic=280.0

Answer (score 0):

Found the relevant documentation [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=layoutperformance_05.html). Seems like that'd be something you'd make a note of on the container docs.